# how to get the startgazer icon for a github repo

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, icons

I am trying to include the stargazer which shows a number of stars of a repo have
in a Nikola generated plan HTML static page.
Something like following

[image]

Is there any UI code to include that ?

Comment: Try https://buttons.github.io/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to https://buttons.github.io and select "Star" and make sure "Large button" and "Show count" is selected. Now, all you need to do is copy the relevant HTML in the "Preview and code" `<textarea>` fields.

Here is the generated code that you will need.

```html
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the button to render. -->
<a class="github-button"
   href="https://github.com/buttons/github-buttons"
   data-icon="octicon-star"
   data-size="large"
   data-show-count="true"
   aria-label="Star ntkme/github-buttons on GitHub">Star</a>
```

Here is a dark version with a specific user and repo (Facebook React):

```css
body { background: #222; }
```

```html
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the button to render. -->
<a class="github-button"
   href="https://github.com/facebook/react"
   data-color-scheme="no-preference: dark; light: dark; dark: dark;"
   data-icon="octicon-star"
   data-size="large"
   data-show-count="true"
   aria-label="Star facebook/react on GitHub">Star</a>
```